MRZ Surname and Visa Mismatch
In my passport the only field is a field called full name (no surname, first name distinction). My name has the following form: A B C D. I always (and consistently) use D as my surname. However, I noticed that my renewed passport MRZ has the form [Country Code] C < D << A < B. Which to my understanding means that the MRZ indicates that my surname is C D. However, this does not agree with a US visa (issued and printed on my new passport), which seems to have the correct MRZ code and specifies my surname (correctly as D). My previous passport's MRZ has D << A < B < C (which is correct).
Can I fly on this new passport?

Yes, it is just an internal field, and BTW it is in the same passport, so how could be interpreted as a different person? Note: we often have different MRZ name, e.g. when a country will transliterate our name, and then automatically transliterated back (so lost of information). Also people without surname are frequent, and every country uses different notation, so... it is just normal

You can certainly fly with this passport. Just make sure you always input your full name when buying tickets and filling travel forms.
You might eventually not be able to use an automatic check in, ticket or passport control machine, but there are fallback employees nearby those places for a reason. And they will let you through after a manual check.

But in this case do I now need to use C, D as my surname? I really just want to consistently use D as my surname and let A, B, C be my given name.

Good luck filling the full name when buying tickets. As you learn from this site, many airline website (and some country websites) cannot handle full names, either because too many characters, or they expect name and surname, or using characters they do not expect. The original question is one of such case: no surname, and so every country and airlines handle it differently (and sometime also inconsistently in the same organization)

@BureacracyDevil Besides some hurdles with automated checks either way will be fine. I would also try to keep it consistent, say you use A B C >> D when buying the ticket, then you should use the same pattern in the esta/health form or whatever other documents you fill out in the same trip.
